# ng-bootstrap datepicker - set default year

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a requirement to set the default year on *ng-bootstrap datepicker*. The problem we have currently is if someone enters `MMDD` and tabs out it defaults to current year (2018) `10-20-2018` but I want it to default it to `10-20-XXXX`.

```html
 <input id="dateControl"
       class="form-control"
       type="text"
       formControlName="dateControl"
       placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY (required)"
       ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"
       [maxDate]="this.maxDate"
       [startDate]="this.minDate"
       [minDate]="this.minDate"/>
```

The requirement is to set the default year on a ng-bootstrap date picker.

Comment: Hi Vinod, I am in need of the same requirement. Did you find any solution?